# Why does `vagrant up` fail the "ifdown eth1" SSH test?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I recently destroyed my homestead box and then re-built. Ever since, I have been getting this error:

```
$ vagrant up
...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

/sbin/ifdown eth1 2> /dev/null

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:
```

The error is a bit cryptic and I can't figure it out. I have re-installed vagrant/virtual-box and purged the config files, but the error persists.

Host: Ubuntu 16.04
Box: Homestead v0.5

Comment: do you have latest version of Vagrant ? It should have been solved after 1.8.1 . To fix you can change from `private_network` to `public_network`

Comment: @FrédéricHenri  I tried it. mine is 1.8.1. Not working

Comment: Ended up just simply re-installing homestead, vagrant, and virtualbox. Not sure what the cause was, but if anyone finds a solution, I am curious.

Comment: For the records: Related ticket on GitHub: [/sbin/ifup eth1 2> /dev/null #1777](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/1777)

Answer (score 2):

For me worked adding **auto_config: false** at the end of network configuration.

```
config.vm.network 'private_network', ip: '192.168.14.10', auto_config: false
```

Comment: that doesn do anything usefull. yes the error will disappear but the network configuration on vm will be incorrect

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else run into the same issue and wants to try something else (worked for me):

I upgraded from Vagrant v1.7.0 to v1.7.4 and the error occurred. Installed Vagrant v1.8.4 and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

There is no interface eth1 in Ubuntu 16.04. It is enp0s3

Comment: Welcome. Thanks for sharing. Your explanation looks good, but maybe you could give a resolution too.

Answer (score 0):

For me, what solved the problem without updating manually the Vagrant version was to install ifupdown package on the VM.

```
vagrant ssh
sudo apt-get install ifupdown
exit
vagrant reload
```

Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-homestead-not-mapping-projects-folder-and-throwing-an-error#

Answer (score 0):

the only thing that has helped to me is to upgrade vagrant version from 1.8.1 to 2.2.14